# import a .xcdatamodel in CoreData CLI

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-data, nsexception

i've a little Problem with a CoreData Command Line Tool. I simply created a new Project in XCode (Core Data CLI), created a Data Model in the .xcdatamodel File and auto generated a Header file. Finaly i modified the Code, wich should able to load the Entity.

The Program Compiles without errors, but if i run the Program i get the following error

```
2010-08-26 20:16:52.031 Core Data Test[866:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Kunde''
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff884bbcc4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff85a630f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
 2   CoreData                            0x00007fff821467a9 +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 153
 3   CoreData                            0x00007fff821798a1 +[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 33
 4   Core Data Test                      0x0000000100001abf managedObjectModel + 95
 5   Core Data Test                      0x0000000100001b7f managedObjectContext + 156
 6   Core Data Test                      0x00000001000019b7 main + 47
 7   Core Data Test                      0x0000000100001980 start + 52
 8   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Abort trap
```

Here's my code: svn://homes.dnsalias.com/CoreDataOwnTesting or simple to copy

```
svn co svn://homes.dnsalias.com:3690/CoreDataOwnTesting
```

Does anyone have an Idea what i am doing wrong? Thank's for your help!
Dennis

***Code added by JLN***

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel();
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext();
NSManagedObjectContext *context;


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    objc_startCollectorThread();

    // Create the managed object context
    context = managedObjectContext();

    NSManagedObjectModel *kunde = managedObjectModel();

    // Save the managed object context
    NSError *error = nil;    
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error while saving\n%@",
              ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}



NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel() {

    static NSManagedObjectModel *model = nil;

    if (model != nil) {
        return model;
    }

    model = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Kunde" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    /*NSString *path = [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0];
    path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mom"]];
    model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    */

    return model;
}



NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext() {

    static NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    if (context != nil) {
        return context;
    }

    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: managedObjectModel()];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];

    NSString *STORE_TYPE = NSSQLiteStoreType;

    NSString *path = [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments] objectAtIndex:0];
    path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"]];

    NSError *error;
    NSPersistentStore *newStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:STORE_TYPE configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error];

    if (newStore == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Store Configuration Failure\n%@",
              ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ?
              [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
    }

    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got some basic problems in the way you're setting up the Core Data Stack. Namely, the first problem (and I stopped there) is that you're trying to create an NSManagedObjectModel instance from an NSEntityDescription. Boom.

Have you read and followed the [Core Data Utility Tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/00_introduction.html)? It's easier for you to follow the tutorial and report on the problems you find there than to parrot its instructions here.

Comment: Yes i have some Basic Problems with Core Data, but i Read (and tried it).
Ok, i see stupid error. But also i do Not able to Load an xcdatamodel.
New question: How do i add a xcdatamodel to a NSManagedObjectModel?

Sorry for my inexplicit first question...

Comment: So ... what's your new code and what errors are you seeing? It's impossible to help you if we don't know what's wrong.